# XCart page showing random code at the top of the page

Tags: html

I'm building a website using x-cart and all of a sudden I'm getting this line of code appearing at the top of the page.

```
class="area-c skin-customer skin-XC_ColorSchemes-customer skin-theme_tweaker-customer authorized target-main no-sidebars">
```

While navigating through the webmaster mode theme tweaker, it appears this line shows up outside what I would expect in the content (that is, when I click on regular page content the relevant file in theme tweaker is highlighted yet nothing happens when I click the code).

Any advice on clearing this away would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The class you see has to be displayed among other attributes for the BODY tag. Since you see it on the page, I guess your HTML markup is broken in some way. This might happen if you edited your template files and left an unclosed tag, or added custom incorrect JavaScript code to the page.

Comment: Which is pretty much what happened. Though rather than being unclosed, I hadn't actually used an opening tag (I've never felt so ashamed). Thanks for getting back to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out in one of my template files there was an if condition followed by a class without an opening bracket.

I think the reason I hadn't spotted this is that rather than matched the text above, the code read along the lines of

```
case="{function.doThis()}>
```